# matplotlibでscatterを使用すると「__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure'」エラーが発生する

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib についての質問です。以下のコードを実行したところ、エラーが発生しました。
`figure`という引数はどのようにして設定できるのでしょうか？

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure'
```

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,1,1,1]
y=[2,2,2,2]
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Comment: 何か環境か版数の問題では？ Windows10 64bit, Python 3.7.6, numpy 1.18.1, matplotlib 3.1.2 ではエラーになりませんでした。あるいはこちらの記事を参考に細かいステップを記述して試してみるとか。[Matplotlibで散布図を描画する方法](https://qiita.com/supersaiakujin/items/ef85dd247cefdfbd2e2a) そういえば以前に Jupyter Notebook の環境で1行づつ別々のセルに入力していると問題があったというQ&Aがあったような？ たとえばこの記事の途中にmatplotlibでscatter図を表示している例がありますので参考に。[Jupyter Notebook を使ってみよう](https://pythondatascience.plavox.info/python%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83/jupyter-notebook%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)

Comment: kunifさんの環境に合わせると、うまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62352/matplotlib%e3%81%a7scatter%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-fi#comment68142_62352)を[回答として転記](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2645/9820)いたします。(改行を追加しています)

> 何か環境か版数の問題では？
>   Windows10 64bit, Python 3.7.6, numpy 1.18.1, matplotlib 3.1.2 ではエラーになりませんでし た。
>   あるいはこちらの記事を参考に細かいステップを記述して試してみるとか。
>   [Matplotlibで散布図を描画する方法](https://qiita.com/supersaiakujin/items/ef85dd247cefdfbd2e2a)
>   そういえば以前に Jupyter Notebook  の環境で1行づつ別々のセルに入力していると問題があったというQ&Aがあったような？
>   たとえばこの記事の途中にmatplotlibでscatter図を表示している例がありますので参考に。
>   [Jupyter Notebook を使ってみよう](https://pythondatascience.plavox.info/python%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83/jupyter-notebook%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)

手元の Win10 64bit, Python 3.6, numpy 1.16.2, matplotlib 3.0.3 でもエラーが再現しませんでした。